# Reading local XML file using javascript and display in html page

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am trying to read xml file through javascript and display it in HTML page.

I am using the following code.

```
function readxml() {
alert("calledreadxml");
var myXML, studentnode;    
myXML= document.all("config.xml").XMLDocumentalert(myXML);
studentnode = myXML.documentElement
var string;
var nxtnode;
while(nxtnode)
{
    string = "the value of "+nxtnode.nodeName+"is :"+ nxtnode.nodeValue+"\n";
    nxtnode = myXML.nextSibling;
}
}
```

this code is nt working.. can anyone please help

Comment: Well, since you can't read local files with JavaScript, you probably are going to be out luck here. Also document.all is an IE way of getting a DOM node, not for reading a file. Also what is XMLDocumentalert?

Comment: there is some [new stuff out there](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) that will let you do that. Once you've read the file take a look at the global objects DOMParser and XMLSerializer.

Comment: Please elaborate on "not working". That is insufficient information. Also, I strongly recommend using a library such as jQuery for this sort of thing. Oh, and as @aquinas says, don't use `document.all`: it doesn't work in most browsers.

Answer (score -3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                           if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                               xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                           }
                           else {// code for IE6, IE5
                               xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                           }
                           xmlhttp.open("GET", "Images-Info.xml", false);
                           xmlhttp.send();
                           xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;


                                                   var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Image_Store");

                           for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
                           {
                              var type = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Image_Type")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                               var title = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Image_Title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                              var des = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Image_Description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                               var ph = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Image_Photo")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                               var thm = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Thumbnail_Photo")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                              // Ul1.innerHTML = Ul1.appendChild("<li><div><a  href=\"" + ph + "\" \><img src=\"" + thm + "\" \/></a><p>" + title + "</p></div><div class=\"data\"><div><h1>" + title + "</h1>" + des + "</div></div></li>");
                               document.write("<li>");
                               document.write("<div>");
                               document.write("<a  href=\"" + ph + "\" \>");
                               document.write("<img src=\"" + thm + "\" \/>");
                               document.write("</a>");
                               document.write("<p>");
                               document.write(title);
                               document.write("</p>");
                               document.write("</div>");
                               document.write("<div class=\"data\">");
                               document.write("<div>");
                               document.write("<h1>");
                               document.write(title);
                               document.write("</h1>");
                               document.write(des);
                               document.write("</div>");
                               document.write("</div>");
                               document.write("</li>");
                           }                
        </script>
```